# Fragment not associated with a fragment manager. (Dialog Fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-dialogfragment, lazy-initialization

I have a dialog fragment, and i make a class for lazy initialization. When i'm showing the dialog, it's showing like normal. but, when i'm dismissing the dialog, it crash caused by : Fragment not associated with a fragment manager.

i have tried to postDelayed dimiss too, but still crashing.

LoadingDialog.kt

```
class LoadingDialog(private val fm: FragmentManager) : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        isCancelable = false
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading, container, false)
    }

    fun showDialog(tag: String? = null) {
        show(fm, tag)
    }

    fun closeDialog() {
        dismiss()
    }
}
```

LazyDialog.kt

```
class LazyDialog<T : DialogFragment>(private val type: Class<T>, private val fm: FragmentManager) :
    Lazy<T> {
    private var dialog: T? = null

    override val value: T
        get() {
            return when {
                type.isAssignableFrom(LoadingDialog::class.java) -> {
                    LoadingDialog(fm).also {
                        dialog = it as T
                    } as T
                }
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown class : ${type.name}")
            }
        }

    override fun isInitialized(): Boolean = dialog != null
}
```

Extensions.kt

```
inline fun <reified T : DialogFragment> FragmentActivity.loadingDialog(): Lazy<T> {
    return LazyDialog(T::class.java, supportFragmentManager)
}
```

LoginActivity.kt

```
private val loadingDialog: LoadingDialog by loadingDialog()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to dismiss it in the `onDestroy` method of a fragment, that was my case at least. Move the `dismiss` method call to the `onStop` of your activity or a fragment.